# .htaccess file not working on linux

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache, httpd.conf

I have configured Amazon EC2 instance with `Amazon Linux AMI 64 bit`

and I have uploaded my website, whole code is working but issue with `.htaccess`

`RewriteRule` are not working. I have done all changes in `httpd.conf` file but I think it might be a permission issue.

please help me regarding this.

here is my `htaccess` code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^friosworld\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.friosworld.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and one more thing I have found via googling

`httpd.conf` file code

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

I think problem is in this block of code. but I don't know what is the problem!

I have also changed `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` but still not working!!

Comment: is mod_rewrite of apache enabled?

Comment: Did you have rewrite module activated?

Comment: Do you launch

    "a2enmod userdir"

and restart apache

Comment: @silentboy how can i active it?

Comment: @SankalpMishra yes it is enabled

Comment: @Oswald no i haven't changed back to `AllowOverride None`

Comment: got solution my own. thanks for your time, now its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. thanks for your time.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All  # AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

**AND**

```
DocumentRoot "/home/mydirectory/website"  //change this default path to my path
```

Now its working fine

Thank you all

Comment: You should change your `<Directory />` directive to `<Directory /home/mydirectory/website>` otherwhise Apache will have to check all directories in your path on each request.